# How can I correct these if conditions

Tags: python, if-statement

For these values, the following code should be correct for the Transition Flow condition which is a combination of seggregated and intermittent flow type. However, this values are also provide seggregated and intermittent flow type at the same time, thats why the code do not calculate the transition flow conditions. I want the code to determine the transition flow type as true than to calculate it, it should recheck the other two condtions of seggregated and intermittent flow.*

```
NLV = 0.428998273922766

NFr=0.0025295272767232994

CL=1.0

L1=316.0

L2=0.0009252

L3=0.1

L4=0.5

angle=90

angle_pi = angle * math.pi / 180

if (((CL < 0.01) and (NFr < L1)) or ((CL >= 0.01) and (NFr < L2))):
      EL_segregated=0
      a,b,c=0.98,0.4846,0.0868
      flow_type="Segregated Flow"
      if (angle >= 0):        #Uphill Flow
          d,e,f,g=0.011,-3.768,3.539,-1.614
      else:                   #Downhill Flow
          d,e,f,g=4.7,-0.3692,-0.3692,-0.5056
          
      β = (1 - CL)*math.log( d*CL**e*(NLV**f*(NFr**g )))
      if β<0:
          β=0
      B = 1 + β * (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi) - (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi)) ** 3 / 3)
      EL0 = a*CL**b / NFr**c
      if EL0<CL:
          EL0=CL
      EL_segregated=EL0*B
      EL=EL_segregated        
          
      
elif ((((0.01 <= CL) and (CL < 0.4)) and ((L3 < NFr) and (NFr < L1))) or ((CL >= 0.4) and (L3 < NFr) and (NFr <= L4))):
      EL_intermittent=0
      flow_type="Intermittent Flow"
      a,b,c=0.845,0.5351,0.0173
      if (angle >= 0):        #Uphill Flow
          d,e,f,g=2.96,0.305,-0.4473,0.0978
      else:                   #Downhill Flow
          d,e,f,g=4.7,-0.3692,-0.3692,-0.5056
      
       
      β = (1 - CL)*math.log( d*CL**e*(NLV**f*(NFr**g )))
      if β<0:
          β=0
      B = 1 + β * (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi) - (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi)) ** 3 / 3)
      EL0 = a*CL**b / NFr**c
      if EL0<CL:
          EL0=CL
      EL_intermittent=EL0*B
      EL=EL_intermittent
      
elif (((CL < 0.4) and (NFr >= L1)) or ((CL >= 0.4) and (NFr > L4))):
      EL_distributed=0
      flow_type="Distributed Flow"
      a,b,c=1.065,0.5824,0.0609
      if (angle >= 0):        #Uphill Flow
          d,e,f,g=1,0,0,0
      else:                   #Downhill Flow
          d,e,f,g=4.7,-0.3692,-0.3692,-0.5056
      
      β = (1 - CL)*math.log( d*CL**e*NLV**f*(NFr**g))
      if β<0:
          β=0
      B = 1 + β * (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi) - (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi)) ** 3 / 3)
      EL0 = a*CL**b / NFr**c
      if EL0<CL:
          EL0=CL
      EL_distributed=EL0*B
      EL=EL_distributed
      
       
elif(L2 < NFr < L3):
      A = ( L3 - NFr)/(L3 - L2)
      B = 1- A
      flow_type="Transition Flow"
      EL_transition = A*EL_segregated + B*EL_intermittent
      EL=EL_transition
```

I wanted to calculate a flow type and the liquid holdup when the CL, NFr, L1, L2, L3, and L4 values are entered as  CL: 1.0, NFr: 0.0025295272767232994, L1: 316.0 , L2: 0.0009252 , L3: 0.1 , L4: 0.5

The flow type should be transition flow. But the code gives this error

```
    EL_transition = A*EL_segregated + B*EL_intermittent

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'EL_segregated' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The point where your code is interrupted is in the last elif:
You try to use the variable "EL_segregated" but the assignment in your first if-branch doesnt get executed, so this variable doenst have a value there.

Edit: add the "python" tag or the tag for the language in general, so you will get more answers in future.

Edit2: Lets be more distinct then. You calculate EL_segregated for the segregated flow case. How do you calculate EL_segregated in the transition flow case?
My guess as per the name of the variable is that its still the same value as in the segregated flow case, so your last elif case is assumably:

```
elif(L2 < NFr < L3):
      flow_type="Transition Flow"

      EL_segregated=0
      a,b,c=0.98,0.4846,0.0868          
      if (angle >= 0):        #Uphill Flow
          d,e,f,g=0.011,-3.768,3.539,-1.614
      else:                   #Downhill Flow
          d,e,f,g=4.7,-0.3692,-0.3692,-0.5056          
      β = (1 - CL)*math.log( d*CL**e*(NLV**f*(NFr**g )))
      if β<0:
          β=0
      B = 1 + β * (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi) - (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi)) ** 3 / 3)
      EL0 = a*CL**b / NFr**c
      if EL0<CL:
          EL0=CL
      EL_segregated=EL0*B

      EL_intermittent=0
      a,b,c=0.845,0.5351,0.0173
      if (angle >= 0):        #Uphill Flow
          d,e,f,g=2.96,0.305,-0.4473,0.0978
      else:                   #Downhill Flow
          d,e,f,g=4.7,-0.3692,-0.3692,-0.5056      
      β = (1 - CL)*math.log( d*CL**e*(NLV**f*(NFr**g )))
      if β<0:
          β=0
      B = 1 + β * (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi) - (math.sin(1.8 * angle_pi)) ** 3 / 3)
      EL0 = a*CL**b / NFr**c
      if EL0<CL:
          EL0=CL
      EL_intermittent=EL0*B

      A = ( L3 - NFr)/(L3 - L2)
      B = 1- A          
      EL_transition = A*EL_segregated + B*EL_intermittent
      EL=EL_transition
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. How can I rearrange the code then to solve that problem?

Comment: I dont know what the value for EL_segregated ought to be in the equation. 
Maybe the same value as in the first if-clause although its another condition?
Just make sure that all variables you use have a value before you use them.